# Error while building Project on qt 5.5.0

Tags: qt, visual-c++, mingw, qt5.5

![Kit error ][1]

In Issue Tab error:

![Qt version][2]

> Qt Creator needs a compiler set up
>   to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.

- Compile Output: 13:45:05: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
- Error while building/deploying project First (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit)
  When executing step "Make".

Comment: Can you tell which compilers do you have? (Tools>Options>Build & Run>Compilers)

Comment: Please add the images that are missing from the post.

Comment: Images are attached below: 
I have tried to uninstall/install 5 times still its not working.
Image1 - "http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ev3nuu.jpg"
Image2 - http://i61.tinypic.com/311m7f8.jpg
Image 3 - http://i62.tinypic.com/1826ig.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Qt for MSVC2013. But you have installed only MinGW compiler. 
There're two ways for solving your problem: 
1) you can change your Qt from MSVC2013 version to MinGW version - download and install [Qt for MinGW](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.5.0.exe) or 
2) you can download and install free version of [Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48131) (that's IDE) for getting it's compiler. After this you just need to choose the correct compiler (MSVC2013) for use if it isn't automatically detected.